# What's the distribution of the difference of two gamma distributions? (the two gamma have same shape parameters)

Tags: probability-distributions

If $X∼\textrm{Gamma}(a,b_1)$ and $Y∼\textrm{Gamma}(a,b_2)$, $X$ and $Y$ are independent, what is the distribution of $X-Y$?

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48378/difference-of-gamma-random-variables

Comment: Thank you for the link, but here the two shape parameters are the same.